# Mercurial equivalent of this git: rename branch and pull remote branch

Tags: git, mercurial

I made some commits on default that I don't want on default. Here's what I'd do in git, what is the mercurial equivalent?

```
git branch -m not_default
git checkout osrf/default
git checkout -b default
```

Here's what I tried (and failed)

```
hg branch -m not_default (default still exists after this)
hg pull -b default osrf (says no changes)
hg update default (does nothing)
```

This doesn't work, and I am left where I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do nothing. Mercurial's branching model is completely different from Git's.

Git requires branch names not just to name branches, but also to keep them alive (so that they don't get garbage collected).

In Mercurial, you can just go back to the original commit, do `hg update` there and make the next commit at that point. This will leave your new commits as an "anonymous branch" (see `hg help glossary`). From there, additional commits will go on a new anonymous branch.

You can use the bookmarks (`hg help bookmark`) to give names to the tips of branches in a Git-like fashion, but strictly speaking, it isn't necessary.

---

In principle, you do not ever have to name a branch or commit in Mercurial. Branches and bookmarks are convenience features for giving structure to the revision graph<sup>1</sup>. The only thing you strictly *need* is `hg update` to move around the revision history to a different commit and then you can add new commits at that point in the revision graph.

If you do that in Git, you will get a "detached HEAD" warning, because this may result in data being lost, but for Mercurial it's not an issue, and that's where the key difference is: In Git, your commands have to preserve the invariant that every commit is reachable from a "ref", so that it won't get garbage collected; Mercurial doesn't have garbage collection, so this invariant is irrelevant and you can move around the history at will.

<sup>1</sup>: Named branches allow you to permanently give a name to a group of commits. Bookmarks allow you to give symbolic names to the tips of branches, which also aren't permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Near the very top of `hg help branch`, you will see this text:

> Note:
>
>   Branch names are permanent and global. Use
>   `hg bookmark`
>   to create a
>      light-weight bookmark instead. See
>   `hg help glossary`
>   for more
>      information about named branches and bookmarks.

Hence, while you can change the *name* that will be associated with *new* commits—including giving new commits a branch-name that has never appeared before, hence creating a *new branch*—you can never change the branch name for existing commits.  **Edit**: [As Reimer Behrends says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42877166/1256452), you generally don't *need* to do this in Mercurial.  Mercurial asserts that you *never* need to do this and simply disallows it.

This is very different from Git, whose "branches" (branch names) are much more like Mercurial bookmarks.  **Edit**: Commits in Git are on *many* branches simultaneously, with each branch name serving to identify the *tip* commit<sup>1</sup> of the thus-named branch, and *reachability* determining which commits are contained within which branches.  (If the number of branches containing a Git commit drops to *zero*, however, the commit *may* be vulnerable to garbage collection, depending on whether it has some non-branch-name name by which it may be found.)  Commits in Mercurial are on exactly one branch, always.  That one branch has one name, always.

(It's technically possible to rename branches by copying a Mercurial repository and using the [Convert Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) to re-map branch names.  The [Evolve Extension is also supposed to be able to do it](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/TipsAndTricks#Rename_a_branch_.28with_the_evolve_extension.29), not that I have tested this.)

---

<sup>1</sup>*Tip commit* is a Git concept that does not have a one-to-one mapping to Mercurial.  A Mercurial *head* is a commit that has no children, and in Git, a branch tip *often* has no children, but a branch tip commit is not *required* to have no children.  In both Mercurial and Git, creating a new commit when the current commit is *X* creates a new child of *X*—but in Git, whatever branch you are "on", if you are on any branch, that branch's name is *rewritten* to point to the *new* commit, which—since it is new and has no children—now *is* the equivalent of a Mercurial head.